# Is it possible to penalize the $k$NN classification algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, regularization, k-nearest-neighbour

I read through [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5742505/) on building an approach to Binary Classification in high-dimensional data. I wondered if there is a way to penalize the regular KNN classification algorithm?

Comment: Penalize what exactly about the alorithm?

Comment: she probably means regularize

Comment: @develarist I understand, yet it is not clear for me what exactly is to be regularized? Is it $k$? Why?

Comment: who knows, ask her

Comment: I've mostly seen regularization/penalization used for parametric estimation; I'm not sure how regularization works, conceptually, for non-parametric classifiers like KNN.

Comment: @develarist this is what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was digging about this question, and I found the following:

I think KNN cannot be penalized. During testing, knn is supposed to find the closest example in the training set and return the corresponding label; it finds the k-nearest neighbors and returns the majority vote of their labels.

**There are many approaches to selecting the best model:**

1. We can choose the model which optimizes the fit to the training data minus a complexity penalty

   $$H^* = \arg \max fit_H( H|D ) − λ complexity( H )$$

The complexity could be measured through parameter counting, for example.

2. We can estimate each model's performance based on the validation set.
   This would estimate of the generalization error.
   $$E[err] ≈ \frac 1{Nvalid}  \sum_{n=1}^{Nvalid} {I(\hat{y} \space (x_n) \neq y_n)}$$
   *Ex. split the given data into train/valid 80-20 split ratio + test set.*
3. Using the k-fold cross validation if the data is small.
   If the split is small such that the $N_{valid}$ would be unreliable to estimate the generalized error, then we can repeatedly train on all-but-1/K and test on 1/K’th. Typically K=10. If $K=N-1$, this is called leave-one-out-CV.

Reference: [CS340-Fall07_L4_knn_ubc_ca](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Teaching/CS340-Fall07/L4_knn.pdf)